# Reading a filename from commandline and opening in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file, filestream, iostream

I want to open a file name received through **command line** and do some changes to it.

I am doing in visual studio. I have my input file in the **same folder where my source code** is. 
But this is not working. What am I doing wrong . Please point it out.

here is my code.

```
 using namespace std;   
  int main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    string input="";
    string output="";
    if( argc == 3 ) {
    input = argv[1];
    output = argv[2];
  cout<"arguments right!";
}
else {
  cout << "wrong entry format. Parameters not correct";
  return 1;
}

infile.open(input.c_str());
if (infile.fail()) 
    cout<<"Could not open file.";
else
    cout<<"File opened perfect ";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your code work if you specify the full path to your input file? The current directory when running your program might not be the same directory where your source is.

Comment: By default, Visual Studio builds your executable in a different directory from the directory containing the source code. If (for example) you pass a full path to the file, it'll (most likely) work fine. Otherwise, you'll need to go into VS's debug options, and set the correct directory you want as the current default when it runs.

Comment: is this okey to use?
string input="C:\CP\Coding\codechef problems\codechef problems\";
input1=argv[1];
input+=input1;
infile.open(input.c_str());

Comment: this is my full path

Comment: Remember that backslashes in string literals need to be escaped or just use forward slashes instead. Although Visual Studio should have warned about that.

Comment: infile.open("C:/CP/input.txt");
i created a file named input.txt.
when I test with (infile.fail()) it test positive. ( fails to open)

Comment: what is the issue.? not able to open though I create a file at the specified folder and opening through

Answer (score 0):

Why not using absolute path.Then no matter how you launch the program,it works fine.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;   
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    string input = "";
    string output = "";
    string work_dir = argv[0];
    //get the directory of program.
    work_dir = work_dir.substr(0, work_dir.rfind('\\') + 1);
    if( argc == 3 ) 
    {
        input = work_dir + argv[1];
        output = work_dir + argv[2];
        cout << "arguments right!";
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "wrong entry format. Parameters not correct";
        return 1;
    }
    infile.open(input.c_str());
    if (infile.fail()) 
        cout<<"Could not open file.";
    else
        cout<<"File opened perfect ";
    return 0;
}
```

Besides,you should put input and output file in the directory of the program.